# Increase time complexity to overcome space complexity

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

So I have an array 'a<sub>0</sub>' of size let's say 10<sup>5</sup>, and now I have to make some changes in this array. The ith change could be calculated using a function f(a<sub>i-1</sub>) to give a<sub>i</sub> in O(1) time, Where a<sub>j</sub> denotes array 'a' after jth change has been made to it. Meaning that a<sub>i</sub> could be calculated if we know a<sub>i-1</sub> in constant time. I know that I have to make 10<sup>5</sup> changes beforehand.

Now the problem asks me to answer large number of queries such as a<sub>i</sub>[p]-a<sub>j</sub>[q], where a<sub>x</sub>[y], represents yth element of the array after xth change has been made to the array a<sub>0</sub>.

Now if I had space of the order of 10<sup>10</sup>, I could easily solve this problem in O(1) by storing all the 10<sup>5</sup> arrays beforehand but I don't (generally) have that kind of space. And I could also answer these queries by each time generating a<sub>i</sub> and a<sub>j</sub> from scratch and answering the queries but I can't afford that kind of time complexity either, so I was wondering if I could monitor this problem using some data-structure.

EDIT: Example:

We define an array B= {1,3,1,4,2,6}, and we define a<sub>j</sub> as the array storing the frequency of ith number after jth element has been added to B. That is, a<sub>0</sub>={0,0,0,0,0,0} now a<sub>1</sub>={1,0,0,0,0,0},  a<sub>2</sub>={1,0,1,0,0,0},  a<sub>3</sub>={2,0,1,0,0,0} a<sub>4</sub>={2,0,1,1,0,0} a<sub>5</sub>={2,1,1,1,0,0} and a<sub>6</sub>={2,1,1,1,0,1}.

f(a<sub>j</sub>) just adds a an element to B and updates the value of a<sub>j-1</sub>.

Comment: Are you trying to minimize time spent per query? Do you know anything about `f(*)`. For instance, does it mutate one or many entries of the array?

Comment: and @Richard Yes, I am trying to minimise time spent per query.

Comment: And my other question: does it mutate one or many entries of the array, or might it have arbitrary function?

Comment: it could mutate many entries, and yes it is arbritrary.

Comment: @Richard let's say we simplify it and assume that the function only changes like 1-5 elements of the array, would it become easier?

Comment: Can you post an example? That would make your question a lot easier to understand.

Comment: @ash: My foremost idea here is that since you can't store all the states, you can accelerate the generation of arbitrary future states by check pointing every X states. If the function changes only a few elements of the array each time, you may be able to decrease the size of the checkpoints and, thus, increase their number.

Comment: @Dukeling ok let me add an example

Comment: @Dukeling I have added an example.

Comment: Does a satisfactory answer need to handle unlimited changes to the entire array at each step, or is it good enough if it only has good performance for a small number of changed elements per step ("like 1-5 elements" as you mentioned)?

Comment: How about once computing all arrays and storing sqrt(10000) = 100 of them. Memory usage: O(n*sqrt(n)). Then for each computation you would select the closest stored array and be left with O(sqrt(n)) computations.

Comment: @Gerriet yes, after posting this question I  came across Square root decomposition(Mo's algorithm), I think that is a good  way to solve this problem

Comment: @Gerriet but that would only work if the changes made are very low.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I think small changes would do too.

Comment: In your example the difference between two consecutive arrays is always just one value. Is this a typical example, or an exceptional one? Should it be expected that from one generation to the next all values will change, or just one, or something unpredictable in between?

Comment: Another thing: you specify what is not acceptable as time and space complexity. But what *is* acceptable to you? Do you have an upper limit as to what the space complexity can be, and another upper limit for the time complexity?

Comment: Do we know anything about the domain of the individual values? Are they integers or floats or anything, and are they within some min/max range?

Comment: @trincot they are integers less than 10^7

Comment: @trincot I am just trying to trincot and I can't specifically say what time complexity I want exactly because I haven't been able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is some a maximum number of states `N`, then checkpoints are a good way to go. For instance, if `N=100,000`, you might have:

```
c0      = [3, 5, 7, 1, ...]
c100   = [1, 4, 9, 8, ...]
c200   = [9, 7, 1, 2, ...]
...
c10000 = [1, 1, 4, 6, ...]
```

Now you have 1000 checkpoints. You can find the nearest checkpoint to an arbitrary state `x` in *O(1)* time and reconstruct `x` in at most 99 operations.

Riffing off of my comment on your question and [John Zwinck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44351963/752843), if your mutating function `f(*)` is expensive and its effects are limited to only a few elements, then you could store the incremental changes. Doing so won't decrease the time complexity of the algorithm, but may reduce the run-time.

If you had unlimited space, you would just store all of the checkpoints. Since you do not, you'll have to balance the number of checkpoints against the incrementals appropriately. That will require some experimentation, probably centered around determining how expensive `f(*)` is and the extent of its effects.

Another option is to look at query behavior. If users tend to query the same or nearby locations repeatedly, you may be able to leverage an [LRU (least-recently used) cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_replacement_policies#Least_Recently_Used_.28LRU.29).

Answer (score 2):

Assume the number of changed elements per iteration is much smaller than the total number of elements.  Store an array of lists, where the list elements are (i, new_value).  For example if the full view is like this:

```
a0 = [3, 5, 1, 9]
a1 = [3, 5, 1, 8]
a2 = [1, 5, 1, 0]
```

We will store this:

```
c0 = [(0, 3), (2, 1)]
c1 = [(0, 5)]
c2 = [(0, 1)]
c3 = [(0, 9), (1, 8), (2, 0)]
```

Then for the query `a2[0] - a1[3]`, we need only consult `c0` and `c3` (the two columns in the query).  We can use binary search to locate the necessary indexes `2` and `1` (the keys for the binary search being the first elements of the tuples).

The query time is then O(log N) for the two binary searches, where N is the maximum number of changes to a single value in the array.  The space is O(L + M), where L is the length of the original array and M is the total number of changes made.